# How to disable pre-selected activity reminders to all users?

Tags: activities, activity-settings

I'd like to disable pre-selected activity reminders to all users.

When user opens a task the Reminder checkbox is pre-selected.

How to make the Reminder checkbox unchecked for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't disabled the checkbox but you can unchecked the `Enable Activity Reminders` from `Activity Setting` to stop sending reminder at all.

[image]

Comment: I do not want to do that. I need to disable the checkbox only. I do not want my users to have pre-selected Reminder checkbox.